# React Native Pass data to another component

Tags: react-native

I am new to  React Native and trying to build a Messenger app and  I have 2 components Search and Messenger​. I am struggling to pass the data I got from Search to Messenger.

Search component finds user (receiver) and me being sender I want to communicate but after finding user in Search I want to pass that user to Messenger so that I can chat with that specific user that found in `<Search>` component.

In addition, Search component has Views that will display user calendar etc.. so ideally I don't want to use `<Messenger>` in render() method of Search as it will include Messenger component features inside the Search component which destroys the purpose of `<Search>` component.

So my code is :

```
'use strict';


var Search = React.cerateClasss({

getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        date: new Date(),
        singerName:''
    };
},
getInitialState: function () {
    return {
        date: this.props.date,
        artistName: '',
        artistUserId: 1,
        maxNoArtist: 0,
        imagePath: '../common/images/1.png',
        user: null
    }
},
getArtistName: function () {
    var artist = [];
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo('userId', this.state.artistUserId);
    return query.first({
        success: (result) => {
            this.setState({artistName: result.get('name')});
            this.props.singerName= result.get('name');
            this.setState({imagePath: result.get('image').url()});
        },
        error: (data, error) => {
            console.log('Error occured : ' + error.message())
        }
    });
},
render: function () {
    if (!this.state.user) {
        return <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={styles.label}> Loading.... </Text>
        </View>
    }
    var username = this.state.user.get('username');


    return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

            <ResponsiveImage source={{uri:this.state.imagePath}} initHeight="200" initWidth="400"/>


            <Text style={styles.label}>
                {this.state.artistName}
            </Text>

            <View style={styles.innerButtonView}>
                <Button text={'Onki'} onPress={this.getPreviousArtistName}/>
                <Button text={'Indiki'} onPress={this.getNextArtistName}/>
            </View>

            <CalendarPicker
                selectedDate={this.state.date}
                onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
                />

            <View style={styles.innerButtonView}>
                <Button text={'Cyk'} onPress={this.onLogoutPress}/>
                <Button text={'Habarlas'} onPress={this.onPress}/>
            </View>

           <Messenger singerName={this.props.singerName}></Messenger> // BREAKS SEARCH COMPONENT PURPOSE - INCLUDES MESSENGER FEATURES IN TO SEARCH COMPONENT

        </View>
    );
},
})


var Messenger = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {
            greeting: 'Salam',
            date: new Date(),
            errorMessage: '',
            user: null,
            olderMessageTextFrom: [],
            olderMessageTextTo: [],
            olderMessageDateFrom: [],
            olderMessageDateTo: [],
            earlierMessages: []
        }
    },
    componentWillMount: function () {
        Parse.User.currentAsync().then((user) => {
                this.setState({user: user})
            }
        )
    },
    getMessages() {
        return [
            {
                text: this.state.greeting,
                name: this.props.singerName,
                image: require('../common/images/1.png'),
                position: 'left',
                date: new Date()
            },
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question. You want to pass data from the Messenger component to the Search component ? And what is the error thrown ?

Comment: Actually it is other way around. I want to pass data from Search to Messenger. I dont get error nor value.

Comment: OK, and in your example, you don't get the singerName right ? Have you tried to do `console.log(this.props.singerName)` in your `render` method of your Search component to see if it is not empty ?

Comment: Yeah you are right I dont get singerName. Yes I tried console.log(this.props.singerName) and I dont get value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am late to answer but I did in different way using `props`.

I have **two components**.

1. `Splash.js`
2. `Home.js`

I am passing the data (Let's take **String**) from `Splash.js` to `Home.js`.

#### First component (Sender)

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Home', {user_name: userName})
```

#### Second component (Receiver)

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.user_name
```

Hope this would help you.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so based on your infos, I think the issue is that you don't get the singerName in the Messenger component.

First, I'd change your `getArtistName` method to this :

```
getArtistName: function () {
    var artist = [];
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    query.equalTo('userId', this.state.artistUserId);
    return query.first({
        success: (result) => {
            this.setState({artistName: result.get('name')});
            // Removed the this.props.singerName = ... 
            this.setState({imagePath: result.get('image').url()});
        },
        error: (data, error) => {
            console.log('Error occured : ' + error.message())
        }
    });
}
```

then in your render method :

```
<Messenger singerName={this.state.artistName} />
```

Inside a component you need to use setState and not change props :
that is to say that `this.props.singerName = 'singer'` is a wrong way of doing things, you should do `this.setState({singerName: 'singer'});` then access it with `this.state.singerName`

Inside your messenger component, you access it with `this.props.singerName`

Comment: Thanks for constructive feedback much appreciated. I have tried above mentioned solution but I have 2 issues. 1. When I add <Messenger singerName={this.state.artistName} /> then all features that live in Messenger component appears on Search page   2. I still dont get singerName in Messenger component.

Comment: Updated previous comment to mention 2 issues. Here is the repo to my app : https://github.com/ckurban/toyagel.git

Comment: I edited my answer. Runs fine and I get the artist with `this.props.singerName` in Messenger component. If you add the component Messenger, it is normal for all features to appear. Maybe add a prop: `<Messenger singerName={this.state.singerName} displayFeatures={false} />` and in messenger component check if `this.props.displayFeatures` is true to display some features.

Comment: When you say : **you should do this.setState({singerName: 'singer'}); then access it with this.state.singerName

Inside your messenger component, you access it with this.props.singerName**   I thought we do use setState when we are changing state rather than prop, but  if I do this.setState({singerName: 'singer'}); then it is changing the singerName prop or do you mean artistName state ?

Comment: Inside the messenger component : you access singerName with `this.props.singerName`
Inside the search component you set it with `this.setState({singerName: 'name')}`
 and access it with `this.state.singerName`

Comment: Nope still does not get it. Here is the code where I am trying to display artist name in messenger component - where did you try in search component :     getMessages() {
        return [
            {
                text: this.state.greeting,
                name: **this.props.singerName**,

Comment: I am keep getting : 2016-02-24 13:19:41.212 [trace][tid:com.facebook.React.JavaScript] Artist name : **undefined**